# Alarm killed on app removed from task manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am setting repeating alarm--

```
int intervalTime = 5 * 1000;

    Intent i = new Intent(context, OnSingleAlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1111,
            i, 0);

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalTime, pi);
        mgr.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pi);
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalTime,
                intervalTime,
                pi);
    } else {
        mgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalTime,
                pi);
    }
```

And alarm is reset in broadcast reciever as--

```
public class OnSingleAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    resetAlarm(context);
   }


private void resetAlarm(Context context) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // Calling same function to re set alarm
    }
}
```

}

And Broadcast reciever is added properly in manifest like--

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcastlisteners.OnSingleAlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

it is working well almost all phones..

But In Lenovo Vibe with model no - Lenovo P1ma40 and OS version 5.1 , alarm is getting killed / removed when i remove app from Task Manager( Running app) . Why it is happening? and how can i stop it?

Thanks in Advance